# dos2unix command is corrupting the file with unicode characters downloaded via binary mode

Tags: linux, ftp, file-transfer, shell-script, binary-files

i downloaded an xml file having unicode characters from ftp in binary transfer mode. In order to remove the line ending special characters i used the command dos2unix. But this is making the file corrupt. Is there a way around?

Answer (score 0):

It should work ([website](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html) and code indicate it knows about Unicode).

You could use a different tool, such as [`tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html), e.g.,

```
tr -d '\r' input >output
```

which will delete all of the carriage-returns giving the intended result if your file does not use carriage returns for overstriking text (the usual case).